# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Android 4.4 or lower

Tags: android-studio

I've got an Android application that I recently upgraded to the Gradle build system among other things, such as using a newer version of build tools, etc.

My targetSdkVersion is 19, so I should be good to go on Android 4.4 and higher. When I run using a 5.0+ device, all is well; however Android 4.4 always crashes with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error of some sort.

As a test, I removed original class that it complained about missing only to have it crash while pointing at a different class.

The first class that it crashed on was an internal private class in a 3rd party library. After removing that library, it pointed to a internal private class in the app itself.

In summary:

- the app runs fine on Android 5.0+. It crashes with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` on anything less than 5.0.
- In tests so far, the NoClassDef always seems to refer to an inner class - this is just based on two tests, so it may not be anything concrete.

Here's my android.manifest file: https://gist.github.com/rscott78/19dd88ccde66172d9332

Answer (score 26):

For what it's worth, this can happen when you enable multi-dex support without adding the correct code in your Application class.

Create a class, have it inherit from Application, then add this override:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
  super.attachBaseContext(base);
  MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

In your AndroidManifest, add a `name` attribute to your application tag:

```
<application name=".MyApplication"
```

Comment: for those who are still needs to add multidexenabled while fixing this error at the same time, this solution will totally save your day!

Comment: But what extra this code did by the way ?? just wanted to know. And yes whoever want to enable multidex along with fix, then this is the solution. +1

Comment: We actually implemented our app this way but we still got the crash. Why?

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I spent hours and glad I found this.  Thanks.

Comment: @bugfixr this is indeed the right answer. Thank you and please mark it as such!

Comment: You can also make your custom Application inherit from MultiDexApplication. It has precisely this code in it

Comment: Excellent Solution!!

Comment: Could you please add an explanation for this?